# Bluetooth LE Android tablet not connecting with Lego Boost Move Hub

Tags: android, bluetooth, lego-mindstorms

I am not able to connect my Android Nexus 7 tablet running the Lego Boost application with the Lego Boost "Move Hub".

How can I make it to work?

Answer (score 8):

The Android Nexus 7 tablet comes with Bluetooth 4.0 which includes Low Energy, aka BTLE (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_7_(2013))

Interestingly, Lego list BTLE 4.1 and higher as compatible Android device (https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/device-guide/boost). In theory I should not be able to connect with BTLE 4.0 (weird?!)

I have been able to install the Lego Boost application on Android 5.1.1 (Kernel 3.4, BTLE 4.0), but was not able to pass the first couple of pop-up screens in the application. The application requires a successful connection with the Move Hub over BTLE before giving access to the building instructions.

After reviewing the documentation provided with Lego Boost, I found a note related to strong electromagnetic interferences and also a way to reset the Move Hub (main brick).

To reset the brick you need to press the green button on top of the hub and keep in pressed for 10 seconds.

After the reset, I was able to connect to the Move Hub over BTLE 4.0 via my Nexus 7 tablet (and got Frankie the Cat going).

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

Went into this and spent a few hours to figure out how to solve it. I will leave a possible solution.
In my case I was using 3 different phones: Iphone 6s & 8, Samsung S9
Lego Boost app ver: 1.9.7
Fw ver: 1.0.00

The bluetooth connection didn’t succeed no matter the sequence of steps I had applied.
Finnaly after I had “hard reset” the Move Hub buy holding the button pressed about 10-15 sec then when I had started the Lego Boost app it started to download a newer ver of firmware.
Now I got 2.0.00.0017 and bluetooth connection works even with Iphone 6s which is not on the listed suported devices.

So I guess after all it was the default factory fw initially written on the Move Hub device which was not compatible anymore with the latest ver of the Lego Boost app.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with lenovo tab 2 a10-70. 
First problem was that BT can not connect to lego boost, because tablet was connected with BT to external loud speaker. I had to disconnect device.
Second problem was that boost denied upload programs until firmware update.
Problem was that BT modul ver 4.0 work with boost, but it is not able to update firmware in the brick. I had to install lego software on newer phone and made update this way.